# How to access dynamically created component

Tags: dynamiccomponent

I have added a component dynamically "ChildContainer" in a div's body. Now I want to access it and want to add again a new component dynamically to the newly create component.

Main Component Markup:

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.init}" value="{!this}"/>
  <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="chk" text="Add" change="{!c.handleChange}"/>
  <div id="MainDiv" aura:id="MainDiv"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller Code:

```
({
init:function(component,event,helper){
    var divCmp = component.find("MainDiv");
    var divBody = divCmp.get("v.body");
    $A.createComponent("c:ChildContainer",
            {
                "Id":"ChildCmp",
                "aura:id": "ChildCmp",
            }, 
             function(newCmp){                    
                divCmp.set("v.body", divBody.concat(newCmp));
            });
},
handleChange:function(component,event,helper){
    var checkCmp = event.getSource();
    var chkvalue = checkCmp.get("v.value");

    if(chkvalue == true){
        var newCmp = component.find("ChildCmp");
        newBody = newCmp.get("v.body");

        $A.createComponent("c:TextBoxComponent",
                    {
                        "Id" : "TBId",
                        "inputText" : "Enter Value",
                        "inputValue":"Test"                        
                    }, 
                     function(newTB){
                       newCmp.set("v.body", newBody.concat(newTB));
                    });
    }
}
})
```

ChildContainer Markup:

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="Id" type="string"/>
  <div id="{!v.Id}" aura:id="{!v.Id}" width="70%">{!v.Id}</div>
</aura:component>
```

TextBoxComponent Markup:

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute type="String" name="Id" />
  <aura:attribute type="String" name="inputText" />
  <aura:attribute type="String" name="inputValue" />

 <div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label">{!v.inputText}</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control">
   <ui:inputNumber aura:id="{!v.Id}" class="slds-input"  value="{!v.inputValue}" placeholder="{!v.inputText}"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</aura:component>
```

Getting undefined error when try to access component using component.find("ChildCmp")